# Getting unwanted dblclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/eF5cp/5/ -  with a resizeable box. If you double click anywhere in the document, the box color toggles between beige and red.

The problem is  that sometimes when you release the left mouse button after resizing the box, a dblclick event is generated and the box turns red. Or sometimes you can release the mouse button without changing the box color, but then if you click just once in the box it generates the dblclick and changes the box color.

Usually, though,  everything works fine.  I have to try maybe 20 times to get a false dblclick event.

I'm using Chrome.

Does anyone see the problem and how to fix it?

Thanks

```
$(function() {
    $("#box").resizable();
    $(document).dblclick(function(e){
        console.log("double-clicked on ",  e.target);
        $("#box").toggleClass("red");
    });

});
```

Comment: You want the `dblclick` even in the box too, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/NGv2e/)***

I would suggest using a flag in order to prevent this behavior. Set the flag when the resize starts, and then *slightly* delay the release of the flag at the end of the resize. I left an alert in my demo so you can see if it gets hit instead of changing color.

```
$(function() {
 var ignoreClick = false;
 $("#box").resizable({
    start:function(){ ignoreClick = true; },
    stop:function(){ 
        setTimeout(function(){
            ignoreClick = false; 
        },100);
    }
 });
 $(document).dblclick(function(e){
    if(ignoreClick){
        alert("prevented");
        return false;
    }
    console.log("double-clicked on ",  e.target);
    $("#box").toggleClass("red");
 });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I could detect if I'm resizing and in that case ignore a dblclick event, but that does't fix the case where the resize completes without a dblclick but then after the resize clicking once in the box generates a dblclick event. More important, what I'm really looking for here is an explanation of the problem ("Does anyone see the problem?") I'll check your answer anyway, though, since it detects resizing  more efficiently than .resize(), which interrupts every few seconds. The moderators feel that asking for the reason I see the dblclick is a new question and should be asked separately.